# How do I configure my linter to auto-correct trailing whitespace errors?

Tags: eslint, whitespace, angular9, lint, autocorrect

I'm using Angular 9, npm 6.14.4 and eslint 4.0.3.  I have defined the lint task as below

```
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "npm run install-puppeteer && ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint -- --fix",
    ...
  },
```

I thouhg tthe "--fix" would correct certain errors, but I'm still getting the whitespace errors ...

```
ERROR: /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/e2e/src/pages/objects.page.ts:97:19 - trailing whitespace
```

Is there something I can do so that the linter can auto-correct these whitespace errors?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having the lint tool fixing whitespace, you can let the editor do the job by creating an [`.editorconfig`](https://editorconfig.org/) file:

```
[*]
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
```